# Mismatch in amazon SQS Metrics for ApproximateNumberOfMessagesDelayed

Tags: amazon-sqs

I have added a delay of 4 seconds to Amazon SQS queue  but while looking at the logs the ApproximateNumberOfMessagesDelayed metric it shows as zero . I am not sure why the delay is not showing up in metrics .

[image]

but in metrics its now showing up.

[image]